# WinSCP for android equivalent

Tags: file-transfer, ssh

Is there a drag/drop ssh client for android so I can connect to my home server via ssh and easily transfer files from server to android phone? something like winSCP for Windows?

Comment: Isn't there a variant of ConnectBot with support for file transfer added?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[ES File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop) is one that can use the secure FTP protocol over ssh protocol.

To get the settings, from ES File Explorer:

- Hit menu key, **Show Tabs**, *Local*, *LAN*, *FTP*, *NET* appears
- Tap on *FTP*
- Then tap on *New* that appears underneath, a dialog box will appear prompting the different FTP types, tap on *SFTP*

[image]

- Enter the details of the ssh server that hosts the secure FTP protocol

[image]

- ES File Explorer will remember the next time, so tap on the server, and then you can browse the file system of the remote server and upload/download files

Comment: How can we ues .ppk key for SFTP?

Comment: @Thompson .ppk keys are specifically for PuTTY. It's more standard to use an id_rsa or id_dsa style OpenSSH key. You can use PuTTYGen to convert your .ppk to an OpenSSH style key.

Comment: I used to use ES File Explorer, but over the past couple of years it has become bloated and laggy on my phone, so I've removed it and replaced it with File Manager + which is much lighter weight. It doesn't do everything that you can do in ES File Explorer, but cut & paste style SFTP is one of the things it does quite nicely.

Answer (score 1):

[Ghost Commander](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ghostsq.commander&hl=en&rdid=com.ghostsq.commander) If you want to go to an opensource client you'll have to add the [SFTP Plugin](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ghostsq.commander.sftp&hl=en)
[AndFTP](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lysesoft.andftp&rdid=lysesoft.andftp) is another client is another alternative but with publicities